# TypeError of null value from HTML items being dynamically created

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React to build a table and the `table` is being created dynamically with `buttons`. So the js functions are being called before the HTML like so:

```
export default function Form() {
  functions() {
    // functions are here
  }

  return (
    <>
       <div>
          All html is here with 
            <form>
            </form>
          and
            <table>
            </table>
       </div>
    </>
   )
}
```

Everywhere I use `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementById`, I receive a
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null` error or
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.
I've tried using `window.onload = function()` for each function, but then the error says `function is not defined`.

Here is a sample of the form
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/deannapi/pen/abpxzWa)

Comment: I don't think this is the right use of React library, instead of using window.onload you can use useEffect with an empty array in the second parameter and then it will be executed onload. and instead of using innerText just try to use states.

Comment: How do I reproduce this in given code pen?

Comment: @TJ for the full react code?

Comment: I clicked around in the code pen and it seemed to work, nothing threw the mentioned errors

Comment: @TJ the codepen isn't even rendering to the table. the only thing that works is the ```console.log()``` but the values aren't being added to the table. Not on mine, at least.

Comment: Because you're not preventing the form submission... please create a [mcve]